# Retrieve BLOB file

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, blob

I upload BLOB files in my SQL database. I create Dynamic Hyperlink redirecting to my downloading.aspx.cs , to download the files .

When I click on it , the only thing I retrieve is something like that :

```
*����JFIF,,��ExifMM*�   ���(1�2;%+>P?`���7��i��%��NIKON CORPORATIONNIKON D3-��'-��'Adobe Photoshop CS4 Macintosh2010:11:19 21:53:25 9�I�@d!ddGddd+�K�r� (��Ƃ�Έ"�'@�0221�֐����� ���� � ��,��42��42��42�0100����Р�d����J����R�b����   � ��Z @( 2010:11:19 20:44:392010:11:19 20:44:39 � ASCII  R030100��(�HH����JFIFHH��Adobe_CM��Adobed����*
```

This is my Page_Load code in this downloading.aspx :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Request["file"].ToString();
    var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"];
    string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    dynamic queryString = ("SELECT Data FROM Files WHERE Name = '" + filename + "'");
    SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
    dbConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read() && reader != null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes;
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Empty);
        bytes = (Byte[])reader["Data"];
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

        reader.Close();
    }

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Can someone tell me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set content type, and add content disposition to your response headers as so:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=whatever.xlsx");
 Response.BinaryWrite(yourbytes);
```

**Note**: content-type has to be specific to the type of file you are streaming. If an image, it has to be something like "image/jpg"; etc. Similarly for the header; if it's an image, probably you want to set the extension on the filename part to be "file.jpg". *Above code is just an example*

Comment: And if I want to download also .cs , visual studio files , pdf ? How should I do ?
Otherwise , your code is perfectly working ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @Emged You need to know the file type you are streaming to the user and set the content disposition and content type appropriately. My advise is that you store the file type on the database as well so you don't have to try and `detect it` analyzing bytes.

Comment: @Emged just use the appropriate mime type for your file.  http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to send Content-Type, Content-Length and Content-Disposition headers to the browser so it can understand the binary data.

Comment: As Icarus said. Thank you for your answer too , it helped me !